# Custom post type not appearing in Wordpress admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing an issue. I'm new in wordpress. I created a function for custom post types. This is my code.

```
function my_cpt(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'SM & Points Templates',
        'add_new' => 'Add New SM & Points Template(s)',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New SM & Points Template(s)',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit SM & Points Template(s)'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title')
    );
    register_post_type('custom_settings', $args);
    $labels1 = array(
        'name' => 'Fine Print',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Fine Print',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Fine Print',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Fine Print'
    );
    $args1 = array(
        'labels' => $labels1,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title')
    );
    register_post_type('fine_prints', $args1);
    $labels2 = array(
        'name' => 'Post Hints',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Post Hint',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Post Hint',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Post Hint'
    );
    $args2 = array(
        'labels' => $labels2,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('editor')
    );
    register_post_type('post_hints', $args2);
    $labels3 = array(
        'name' => 'States',
        'add_new' => 'Add New State',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New State',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit State'
    );
    $args3 = array(
        'labels' => $labels3,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title')
    );
    register_post_type('states', $args3);
    $labels4 = array(
        'name' => 'Help',
        'add_new' => 'Add Help',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Help',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Help'
    );
    $args4 = array(
        'labels' => $labels4,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title')
    );
    register_post_type('helps', $args4);
}

add_action('init',  'my_cpt');
```

The issue is that **First 4** posts are appearing in admin menu. But last `Helps` is not appearing in menu bar. Where am I wrong? Please see the this image.

[image]

After `States`, there should be `Help`.

EDIT:

When I was adding the last custom post, I made a small mistake. I added this code.

```
$labels4 = array(
    'name' => 'Help',
    'add_new' => 'Add Help',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add Help',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Help'
);
$args4 = array(
    'labels' => $labels4,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array('title')
);
register_post_type('states', $args4);
```

Now the last two custom post types had same id `states`. But when I saw it, I changed it to `helps`. It was appearing when I added it for the first time with `states` id. But when I changed it to `helps`, It disappeared. In the top menu, `Helps` is visible under **New** but not in admin menu.

Comment: your code is correct and work here as well looks like you may be cache issue please clear the cache and try again

Comment: I checked it in 3 different browsers, but the same error persists in all 3 browsers.

Comment: I have also tested your code and it worked correct on my installation.

Comment: ok do one thing open your wp-config file and define('WP_DEBUG', false); set it to true define('WP_DEBUG', true); then check is there any error shows

Comment: Okay let me do this.

Comment: I enabled debug mode. When I refresh the dashboard, I see no errors.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. There was a conflict with plugin WooCommerce Deals. When I deactivated it, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the final menu must appear because the code is right..Try to make the last menu in a separate function and hook..maybe it appears like:

```
function my_custom_post_type(){
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Help',
    'add_new' => 'Add Help',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add Help',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Help'
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt',
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array('title')
);
register_post_type('helps', $args);
}

add_action('init',  'my_custom_post_type');`
```

Comment: cpt is basically created but it is not appearing on the admin menu...May be these arguments may help you:..                                                              'show_ui' ,'show_in_menu', 'show_in_nav_menus', 'menu_position'

Comment: Have you try menu_position like 'menu_position' => 5 or whatever where u want to show..?,